# I'm getting an IllegalStateException by using createBufferStrategy(3);

Tags: java

When I try to run this method, I get an IllegalStateException. It says there's an error where it says "createBufferStrategy(3);"

```
public void render(){
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs==null){
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.drawOval(10, 10, 32, 32);
        bs.show();
        bs.dispose();
        g.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Is the component which is generating the buffer attached to a native peer (ie some kind of window) and is it visible on the screen?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think so. How do I make sure?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! @MadProgramer was correct on what he said. To be exact, all I had to do was add two lines of code:

```
Main main = new Main();
frame.add(main);
```

If you were searching for the same question, I hope this answered it.

Have a nice day,

Lt Lobster